# Extract string before and after keyword using special character as start and end positions to be extracted in Linux

Tags: string, grep, pattern-matching, special-characters, newline

I have a log file like the following one. It does not have any consistency in terms of format. I have been able to remove all  non necessary new lines so that each Warning is in a new line.

```
Warning: Variants 'aaa8212' and 'bbb2388_ver2' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'ccc9186' and 
'ddd225581' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'e223513' 
and 'ffff13855' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'gg08395' and 'hhh34224' have the
same 
position.
Warning: Variants 'iii454353428' and 'jjjjjj82428' have the same
position.
Warning: 6000 het. haploid genotypes present (see Tet_merged.hh ); many
commands treat these as missing.
Warning: Nonmissing nonmale Y chromosome genotype(s) present; many commands 
treat these as missing.
```

My output looks like this:

```
Warning: Variants 'aaa8212' and 'bbb2388_ver2' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'ccc9186' and 'ddd225581' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'e223513' and 'ffff13855' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'gg08395' and 'hhh34224' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'iii454353428' and 'jjjjjj82428' have the same position.
```

In order to get this output I have used the following command:

```
cat Test_lines.txt | grep "'" | awk '/position\.$/ {print; next} {printf "%s ", $0}' Test_lines.txt
```

First, I extracted the Warning lines containing a single quote (the ones I'm interested in) and afterwards I printed only those lines ending in "position." and I removed all other extra new line characters.

However, I would like to extract for each Warning line the string between single quotes before and after the " and " string. In this case the desired output should be:

```
'aaa8212' and 'bbb2388_ver2'
'ccc9186' and 'ddd225581'
'e223513' and 'ffff13855'
'gg08395' and 'hhh34224'
'iii454353428' and 'jjjjjj82428'
```

For this last purpose, I have tried to use the following syntax:

```
cat Test_lines.txt | grep "'" | grep -o -P '.{0,3} and .{0,4}'
```

But this syntax relies on positions and not on delimiters such as the single quote. Is there any way I can substitute a specific positions for the nth presence of a specific delimiter, in this case the single quote?

Thank you very much,

Best,

Yatrosin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single GNU **`awk`** command:

```
awk -v RS='\\<position\\.' \
'/\047/{ gsub(/^[^\047]+|\n+|[^\047]+$/, ""); print $0 }' Test_lines.txt
```

The output:

```
'aaa8212' and 'bbb2388_ver2'
'ccc9186' and 'ddd225581'
'e223513' and 'ffff13855'
'gg08395' and 'hhh34224'
'iii454353428' and 'jjjjjj82428'
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how this one works? It works perfectly in my test file, but it does not work with the actual log file I need to process.

Comment: This one also works, but it is missing a space after the "and" for certain lines. My entire log file may be more complex than my example. I was using a wrong input file. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `awk`'s output to `grep -o "'.*'"` , so the commands would be:

```
cat Test_lines.txt | grep "'" | 
awk '/position\.$/ {print; next} {printf "%s ", $0}' Test_lines.txt

cat Test_lines.txt | grep -o "'.*'"
```

Full Example:

```
echo "Warning: Variants 'aaa8212' and 'bbb2388_ver2' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'ccc9186' and 'ddd225581' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'e223513' and 'ffff13855' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'gg08395' and 'hhh34224' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'iii454353428' and 'jjjjjj82428' have the same position.
" -n | grep "'" | awk '/position\.$/ {print; next} {printf "%s ", $0}' | grep -o "'.*'"
```

Output:

```
'aaa8212' and 'bbb2388_ver2'
'ccc9186' and 'ddd225581'
'e223513' and 'ffff13855'
'gg08395' and 'hhh34224'
'iii454353428' and 'jjjjjj82428'
```

Comment: The output that I get for this command is the following:'aaa8212' and 'bbb2388_ver2'
'ccc9186'
'ddd225581'
'e223513'
'ffff13855'
'gg08395' and 'hhh34224'
'iii454353428' and 'jjjjjj82428'. Some "and" are missing and these specific variants should be in the same line, but they are actually written to two different lines.

Comment: Isn't the output mentioned in the answer what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, but not what I get. If you look carefully my previous comment, ccc... -ddd.., e...-ffff... and gg...-hhh... have no "and" in between and they are printed in different lines.

Comment: I do not get the same result you proposed. Try passing the output directly from `awk` to the `grep -o "'.*'"`?

Comment: Try the example I added.

Comment: Don't worry. It was my fault. It actually works. Thanks